# rsync and (post) process synced file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, imagemagick, rsync

i like rsync my photos from one (linux) disc partition to an other (backup location) using an shell script.
The problem is, that I need to re-scale all photos which are saved on the backup location, for example with `mogrify`.

Is it possible to post-process every file, which is synced/copied by rsync?
In oder to execute `mogrify` on every synced file?

An other way could using rsync (only) to generate the list of files which have to be synced. Next step: run a loop to `mogrify` every list entry in order to output the scaled photo to the backup location.

The problem is, that I have to add all the directories and child-directories to keep the original folder structure before saving the photo.

Using rsync would handle the folder creation "on the fly".

So: is it possible to execute an command on every file synced with rsync?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`rsync` has a `-i`/`--itemize-changes` flag to output a resume of what it does with each file.

I suggest you to play a bit with it, I'm seeing it outputs lines like `>f+++++++++ file1` for a new file, `>f..T...... file1` for an unchanged file, `>f.sT...... file1` for an update, etc...

Having that, you can read this output into a variable, and parse this with `grep` and `cut`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
log=$(rsync -i rsync-client/* rsync-server/)
newFiles=$(echo "$log" | grep '>f+++++++++' | cut -d' ' -f2)
for file in $newFiles
do
    echo "Added file $file"
done
```

Comment: great. That's it! :-). I added -a option to work recursive. `rsync -ia rsync-client/* rsync-server/`

Comment: I'm trying to figure this out myself, but I think `>f..T...... file1` is not what you would see with an unchanged file. The ">" means a transfer or update is happening. If no transfer or update happens, the ">" is replaced by a dot, as in `.f..T...... file1`.